# How to add more objects to my file every time i run my program?

Tags: java, file, object, file-io

This is my `saveTable` button which saves one row of my table and than puts it into my `Auto.auto` file,but i can only save one `object(row)` of `Auto type`. Every time i save another `line(row)` it replaces the old one whith the new one so at the end i have only one `object(row of table)` in my file after clicking save button for like 5 times while my program is running. How can I solve this?

```
        saveTable.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int row = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            getText.getAuto(row);
            File tabel = new File("C:\\Users\\Jovan\\Desktop\\Auto.auto");
            try {
                if (!(tabel.exists())) {
                    tabel.createNewFile();
                }
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(tabel);
                ObjectOutputStream oos1 = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos1.writeObject(getText.getAuto(row));
                oos1.close();


                ObjectOutputStream os2 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(tabel, true)) {
                    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
                        reset();
                    }
                };

                os2.writeObject(getText.getAuto(row));
                os2.close();




            } catch (IOException  error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    });
```

Comment: What about `fos`? Shouldn't it be `new FileOutputStream(tabel,true);`?

Answer (score 1):

```
new FileOutputStream(tabel, true)
```

The second parameter means that you will append to that file instead of overwriting it

> public FileOutputStream(File file,
>                   boolean append)
>                    throws FileNotFoundException
>
> Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the specified File object.
>   If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end
>   of the file rather than the beginning. A new FileDescriptor object is
>   created to represent this file connection. First, if there is a
>   security manager, its checkWrite method is called with the path
>   represented by the file argument as its argument.
>
> If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does
>   not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other
>   reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.

Reference [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean))